# Redirecionar para outra página apenas se o usuario for autenticado

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Tenho uma tela de login onde faço autenticação de um usuário, porém quando coloco um `action` para mudar de página independente se o usuário foi autenticado ou não a página é aberta.

Minha dúvida é pra saber onde eu tenho que fazer a verificação se o usuário está autenticado ou não para redirecionar?

Botão:

```
<f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="Entrar" update=":msgGlobal"
            actionListener="#{usuarioBean.entrar}" action="principal?faces-redirect=true"/>
</f:facet>
```

Método que faz a autenticação:

```
public void entrar() {
    try {
        UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
        usuarioLogado = usuarioDAO.autenticar(usuarioLogado.getLogin(),
                    usuarioLogado.getSenha());
        if (usuarioLogado == null) {
                FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Login ou Senha inválidos");
        } else {
                FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Usuario Autenticado com Sucesso");
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao tentar entrar no Sistema");
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54272/discussion-on-question-by-diegoaugusto-redirecionar-para-outra-pagina-apenas-se)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void entrar() {
    try {
        UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
        usuarioLogado = usuarioDAO.autenticar(usuarioLogado.getLogin(),    usuarioLogado.getSenha());
        if (usuarioLogado == null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(/* url que vc quer*/);
        } else {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Usuario Autenticado com Sucesso");
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(/* url que vc quer*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Funcionou